# Update weight of a product with jquery upon select.

Tags: expresso-store, modifiers

I am currently using a modification on a certain product.  It's set up basically as a price modifier however, the weight on one of the products has changed.

Is possible to modify the weight on a selected modifier without creating a separate product?

```
$('modifiers[10]').change(function(){
if($(this).val() == '42'){ 
$('.store_product_weight').text(' 44<small>lb.</small>/ 5<small>Gal</small>Pails'); // Change Text
}
});
```

I'm pretty sure I can modify the text but what about the actual value?

Thanks

Comment: What was your final solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

To modify the actual weight of the item so that it adjust things like shipping weight you would need to write an extension ([available hooks](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/extension_hooks.html)) that would adjust the actual values for calculations.